# Update statement taking long but select is fast

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Update is running over a minute but select runs under a second, I have created indexes and checked for fragmentation all tables are in good state.

```
UPDATE [PERSEUS].[ODSDB].dbo.IN_STG_EOM_ORDERS_LINE
SET OrderShippingStatusId = 205,    OrderShippingStatus = 'Sent to Vendor (via service)'

FROM [PERSEUS].[ODSDB].dbo.IN_STG_EOM_ORDERS_LINE
WHERE OrderExternalOrderID = '012354244'
    AND OrderShippingStatusId = 204 AND 
        ItemProduct_ProductPartNo IN (SELECT ORD_LIN.sku
                                          FROM [PS_VendorPortal].[dbo].[PA_PORTAL_SUBMIT] P_SUB
                                          INNER JOIN PERSEUS.ps01.dbo.pa_order_lin ORD_LIN WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                            ON P_SUB.[ORD_ID] = ORD_LIN.order_no AND P_SUB.[ORD_LINE] = ORD_LIN.SEQ 
                                            WHERE P_SUB.[ORD_ID] = 'DTCI012354244-A')
```

Comment: Is there any triggers on that table?

Comment: It could be you have index on column OrderShippingStatusId or OrderShippingStatus

Comment: How many rows does this query affect?

Comment: Maybe your select returns only one part of the whole set of data.

Comment: There are no triggers on any of the tables.

Comment: This affects 3 record rows  my select returns the 3 rows under a second

Comment: Yikes - using 2 different linked server from a (presumably) third instance. And, of course, splattering NOLOCK hints about the code.

Comment: I do have a index on OrderShippingStatusId is that not wise?

Comment: its only one linked server [Perseus] thats on same domain.

Comment: Can any one provide a solution?

Comment: Hi @milltonion when you have index on some column then the this index helps select statement to be faster. But when updating the index also needs to be updated and this will slow the update statement.

Comment: still looking for answer on this? #Bump